# Who am I? (short)

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

> I am a chapter in a world of fantasy.
>
> A chapter filled with death and grief beyond any scope.
>
> Many fear me and the tune I bring,
>
> But I am essential to beat the greater evil  that lies ahead.
>
> To succeed you must reveal what lies beyond the sylph,
>
> And you will be rewarded with a tune to fight the beast.

**Hint 1:**

> Take my first and bloodsuckers stand no chance.

**Hint 2:**

> Pay attention to what ends the second and fifth line.

**Hint 3:**

> It might help if you had game as a child.

I might be overdoing it with the hints, try and solve it without them

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Just a note - usually posters on this site tend to not put hints up initially, to encourage solvers to think about the puzzle first.  Also, why don't you take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and earn your first badge?

Comment: Oh sorry about that, should I take them down?

Comment: People will be able to see in the edit history anyway. Just maybe a note for next time.

Comment: As this puzzle requires very specific knowledge, please tag appropriately.

Comment: I'm new to this, sorry about that. What tag would be appropriate in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Partial answer:

> Pretty sure it is related to Pokemon, more specifically, the Lavender City part of the original games.

Not in order, but the clues and hints indicate that:

I am a chapter in a world of fantasy/ A chapter filled with death and grief beyond any scope

> Yup, Pokemon is definitely a world of fantasy last time I checked.

Pay attention to what ends the second and fifth line

> The words "scope" and "sylph" relate to the Sylph Scope, an item needed to identify (and thus battle) the ghost-type Pokemon in Lavender Tower.

Many fear me and the tune I bring/ But I am essential to beat the greater evil that lies ahead.

> The "boss battle" of the quest is a Marowak which has been haunting the Tower for a long time, thus a 'greater evil'.

To succeed you must reveal what lies beyond the sylph/ And you will be rewarded with a tune to fight the beast

> The reward for clearing this quest is a Pokeflute which allows one to battle Snorlax, quite a beast indeed.

Sadly, knowing all this still doesn't quite point out exactly what the answer is, and how some of the other clues fit. Anyone?

Comment: nicely done! +1, this is correct! I'll accept this once all the clues are dealt with. (still don't have enough rep to +1 you immediately)

Comment: I might have confused you with using the word "chapter". If I wrote "place" I thought it would have been too obvious. "chapter" here is meant to portray as lavender town being a part of the pokemon story progression.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Crossbones?

Explanation as follows

I am a chapter in a world of fantasy.

> Crossbones in Fantasy Fight Game/Comics

A chapter filled with death and grief beyond any scope.

> Used as a sign of danger

Many fear me and the tune I bring,

> Some fear skull and most of the time it represents death.

But I am essential to beat the greater evil that lies ahead.

> Helps people to be aware of danger ahead.

To succeed you must reveal what lies beyond the sylph,

> 

And you will be rewarded with a tune to fight the beast.

> 

**Hints**

> Take my first and bloodsuckers stand no chance.

> > Vampires fear cross

> Pay attention to what ends the second and fifth line.

> > 

> It might help if you had game as a child.

> > Fantasy Fight game

Comment: Wow, I like this answer, unfortunately it's not the correct one. You are right about how it's a game though! Maybe that'll help.